# Keeping HTML5 controls on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html

We are using jplayer to display HTML5 videos.  We want our users to have the option of skipping the videos with a seek bar.  On IE, FF and Chrome, the seek bar only appears if the mouse is over the video, otherwise it's hidden.  Our older customers may not know to scroll over the video to see the seek bar.  Is there a way to keep the controls on the screen at all times?  I have tried to use wrappers in js/jquery but with no luck.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any specific experience with `jplayer`, but I'd try the [API documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/). There's an `autohide` property in there that looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Let me quote some text from documentation:

> autohide †

```
object : Sets the auto-hide options for the GUI in the screen display states.

Object Properties:

restored
    Boolean : (Default: false) : Auto-hide the GUI when in the restored screen display state.
full
    Boolean : (Default: true) : Auto-hide the GUI when in the full screen display state.
fadeIn
    Number : (Default: 200) : The period of the fadeIn animation in milliseconds.
fadeOut
    Number : (Default: 600) : The period of the fadeOut animation in milliseconds.
hold
    Number : (Default: 1000) : The period of the pause before autohide begins in milliseconds.
```

We have here HOLD option. The only way i found is to set this value to 9999999999 for example.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using a GUI, changing that is taking no effect.  The controls look different in each browser, so it looks like it's a default player of some kind.

Comment: It looks like it's standard HTML5 video code rather than using jplayer.